# Wi-Fi calls with Csip simple

Tags: wi-fi, calls, samsung-galaxy-y

I am testing Wi-Fi calls with Asterisk, a SIP server.
I tried using [CSipSimple](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.csipsimple) and mizurdoid.
In both the cases the voice path establishes very rarely
Most of the time no call goes through.
After thee call the CSipSimple says unexpected error and recommends force close.
I am using Samsung Galaxy Y. Please advise.

Comment: What Android version is running on your SGY? If 2.3 or higher: You know Android has a native (built-in) SIP client? You could try that.